# Select-Object selecting multiple objects but splitting the results and trimming them export to CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have a script that reads from a list of computers, does a test connection. If it gets a reply from the `Test-Connection`, it does a if/else and builds a variable from a `Get-ChildItem` that reads from the suspect system `C:\Users` to see the last person to log in and select the name and last write time of the last user that logged in, and does a `Write-Host` of the results. If the `Test-Conneciton` didn't get a reply, it builds a variable of the system name with a "offline" statement and does a `Write-Host` to show it. Then, to finish it all off, it exports the results to a CSV.

Several things I am having issues with:

- The variable for the `Get-ChildItem` does a `Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime` and builds the results into a variable.  I would like to display those results (and of course export them into the CSV) separately instead of combined.
- I need to trim the results or modify the script so it doesn't include extra characters in the results.

Here is an example of the results from the Get-ChildItem when the `Test-Connection` gets a reply from the machine (of course system name, IP address and user name have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
SYSTEMNAME @{IPV4Address=192.168.0.1} @{Name=John.Doe; LastWriteTime=03/08/2017 08:11:48}
```

The name and last write time are combined in the results and I need to split them out in the display and the CSV export as well as trim the extra characters.  Something like this, where systemname, IP address, name and lastwritetime would all appear in their own cells in the CSV:

```
SYSTEMNAME 192.168.0.1 Name=John.Doe  LastWriteTime=03/08/2017 08:11:48
```

Code below:

```
$computerList = Get-Content "D:\filelocation\LastLogIn.txt"
foreach ($Computername in $computerList) {
  $ipreachable = Test-Connection $computerName -EA SilentlyContinue -Count 1 |
                 select IPV4address
  $output =@()
  if ($ipreachable) {
    $LastUserLoggedIn = Get-ChildItem "\\$computername\c$\Users" -EA SilentlyContinue |
                        Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
                        Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime -First 1
    $Details = "$LastUserLoggedIn"
    Write-Host $computername $ipreachable $Details
  } else {
    $details = "$computerName Computer does not exisit or is offline"
    Write-Host $Details
  } 
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    SystemName = $Computername
    IPV4Address = $ipreachable
    UserLogInDetails = $details
  } | Export-Csv "D:\filelocation\lastuserreults.csv" -NoType -Append
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the IP address:

```
... | Select-Object -Expand IPV4Address | Select-Object -Expand IPAddressToString
```

and don't turn the directory information into a string:

```
$Details = "$LastUserLoggedIn"
```

Build your data object like this:

```
$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
  SystemName  = $Computername
  IPV4Address = $ipreachable
  UserName    = $LastUserLoggedIn.Name
  Timestamp   = $LastUserLoggedIn.LastWriteTime
}
```

So that you can display the information on the console as well as export it to a CSV:

```
$obj | Format-Table -AutoSize
$obj | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' -NoType -Append
```

Comment: Thank you.  it trims the IP and Name perfectly, however, it is having other issues now.  It is holding the information for the following variables and populating them to all systems down the list. :
    UserName    = $LastUserLoggedIn.Name
    Timestamp   = $LastUserLoggedIn.LastWriteTime

All other variables are giving the correct output.

Comment: You need to reset `$LastUserLoggedIn` with every iteration, otherwise the variable will retain the values from a previous iteration if a host isn't reachable.

Comment: Thank you.  that was the problem.  I put a clear-variable LastUserLoggedIn in and it is exactly what i needed.
Thank you for the help